# How to set up a Spring Batch single reader with multiple itemwriters?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I've a situation where I've to perform DB operations to 2 different databases as shown below.

```
stepBuilderFactory.get("some text")
                  .<POJO,POJO>chunk(200) 
                  .reader(dataReader)
                  .writer(writeToDB1)
                  .writer(writeToDB2) 
                  .faultTolerant()
                  .skipLimit(10) 
                  .skip(DataAccessException.class)
                  .build();
```

Only the second writer is getting executed, ignoring the first writer. Can this can be achieved using `Spring Batch 3.x` & `Spring Boot 1.5.x`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch: How to create a Composite Item Writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967932/spring-batch-how-to-create-a-composite-item-writer)

Answer (score 1):

[CompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) is what you need. It allows you to compose delegate writers to write items to multiple destinations.

When your delegate writers are `ItemStream`s (which is apparently the case for you), you need to register them as streams in the step so that their callback methods from the `ItemStream` interface are properly called at the necessary points of the step lifecycle (or in short, so that their `ItemStream` contract is correctly honored). You can find more details on this in the [Registering ItemStream with a Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#registeringItemStreams) section of the reference documentation.

Hope this helps.